# angular expression not working for html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I'm using angular grid -

let's say i have a scope object as follows:

```
$scope.test = 3
```

If I want to dynamically set an html id, I would do something like this:

```
<div id="{{test}}"></div>
```

Checking the DOM, I see the following:

```
<div id="3"></div>
```

For my angular grid, I want to do something like this:

```
<div ag-grid="{{test}}"></div>
```

Checking the DOM I literally get:

```
<div ag-grid="{{test}}"></div>
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example to question.

Comment: have you defined test in the controller's scope?

Comment: yes, test is in the controller's scope as it was verified with the simple id example

Comment: take a look at this forum thread - http://ag-grid.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=2934

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to achieve, but the thread did not contain any answers...

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngAttr and do this like the following:

```
ng-attr-ag_grid="{{test}}"
```

Please check if this helps

Comment: The DOM literally shows: ng-attr-ag-grid="{{test}}"

Comment: What is angular version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<div ag-grid="test"></div>
```

Check following [link](http://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-grid/index.php) and check first example `html` file for`ag-grid` tag with binding variable

Note: Based on example `test` should be `object` not `string` or other type.

Answer (score 0):

Is `{{ }}` necessary?
You can try:
ag-grid="test"

Comment: this gives me <div ag-grid="test"></div>...I am looking for <div ag-grid="3"></div> as per the scope variable